# Is there a popular non-Google Korean-English-Korean translator app?

Tags: online-resources, south-korea, communication

In South Korea, there are popular alternatives to many of Google's online services, for example Naver's web portal (search) and maps app and KakaoTalk (messaging).

Is there a Korean-English/English-Korean translation app similarly popular here?

Comment: Hay David - just for clarity, why does one look for an alternative to google?  is it slow there, or ??

Comment: @JoeBlow google is not as accurate as people think ... and I'd trust better the koreans to do a specialized tool for korean language than others

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Naver provides one: [see here](http://translate.naver.com).

It also provides a English-Korean dictionary: [link's here](http://endic.naver.com).

Comment: Awesome! Just tried the translate-then-reverse-translate test for a few useful phrases and the Naver web app did way better than Google Translate.

Comment: @davidvc I hope this is not too off-topic but why would you need to translate-then-reverse-translate?

Comment: Hi @JaneDoe1337 - that's the classic **quick test** to see how well translation software works.